# sorting a List of Map<String, String>

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a list variable created like this:

`List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();`

In my Android application, this list gets populated.

just an example:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "Josh");
...

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "Anna");
...

Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "Bernie");
...

list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
list.add(map3);
```

I am using `list` to show results in a `ListView` by extending `BaseAdapter` and implementing the various methods.

My problem:  I need to sort `list` in alphabetical order based on the map's key **name**

Question: What is a simple way to sort `list` in alphabetical order based on the map's key **name**?

I can't seem to wrap my head around this.  I have extracted each **name** from each `Map` into a `String` array, and sorted it(`Arrays.sort(strArray);`).  But that doesn't preserve the other data in each `Map`, so i'm not too sure how i can preserve the other mapped values

Comment: @DLK, and knowing how to write a custom comparator is just what binnyb is finding out.

Comment: Both @Jon Skeet and @JB Nizet's answers have correctly pointed out that `Map` is probably a bad choice for your records.  A custom class with attributes / getters / setters would be better.  Why?  1) robustness / type safety, 2) memory usage, 3) performance, 4) simpler code.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll be looking into changing how i have it set up.

Comment: this is my first time ever needing to sort something in java programming other than using the SQL `order by`. i have tried searching for answers before asking, and i couldn't find a sufficient answer to my problem. sorry to bother!

Comment: @binnyb - Don't apologize. I googled for a solution to this, and your question came up offering al these great answers. Coming from a different platform i didnt know about comparators, and now, within minutes, i do. Those are the wonders of StackOverflow. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following code works perfectly

```
public Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
        return m1.get("name").compareTo(m2.get("name"));
    }
}

Collections.sort(list, mapComparator);
```

But your maps should probably be instances of a specific class.

Comment: thanks, this did it(with minor syntax fixes).  i will be looking into creating a specific class for the list, i never thought of doing that.

Comment: I don't know what you store in the maps, but if it's only static attributes, (name, firstName, age, etc.), then you should even replace the map by a Class (example : class Person {private String name; private String firstName, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

You should implement a `Comparator<Map<String, String>>` which basically extracts the "name" value from the two maps it's passed, and compares them.

Then use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Are you sure a `Map<String, String>` is really the best element type for your list though? Perhaps you should have another class which *contains* a `Map<String, String>` but also has a `getName()` method?

Answer (score 7):

```
@Test
public void testSortedMaps() {
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("name", "Josh");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("name", "Anna");

    Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map3.put("name", "Bernie");

    List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    mapList.add(map1);
    mapList.add(map2);
    mapList.add(map3);

    Collections.sort(mapList, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(final Map<String, String> o1, final Map<String, String> o2) {
            return o1.get("name").compareTo(o2.get("name"));
        }
    });

    Assert.assertEquals("Anna", mapList.get(0).get("name"));
    Assert.assertEquals("Bernie", mapList.get(1).get("name"));
    Assert.assertEquals("Josh", mapList.get(2).get("name"));

}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to make use of lamdas and make it a bit easier to read

```
  List<Map<String,String>> results;

  Comparator<Map<String,String>> sortByName = Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get("Name"));

  public void doSomething(){
    results.sort(sortByName)
  }
```

Comment: This answer helped me solve issue I was facing using thenComparator in a cleaner way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a comparator.  I am not sure why each value needs its own map but here is what the comparator would look like:

```
class ListMapComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
         Map<String, String> test1 = (Map<String, String>) obj1;
         Map<String, String> test2 = (Map<String, String>) obj2;
         return test1.get("name").compareTo(test2.get("name"));
    }
}
```

You can see it working with your above example with this:

```
public class MapSort {
    public List<Map<String, String>> testMap() {
         List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
         Map<String, String> myMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         myMap1.put("name", "Josh");
         Map<String, String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         myMap2.put("name", "Anna");

         Map<String, String> myMap3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         myMap3.put("name", "Bernie");


         list.add(myMap1);
         list.add(myMap2);
         list.add(myMap3);

         return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MapSort ms = new MapSort();
         List<Map<String, String>> testMap = ms.testMap();
         System.out.println("Before Sort: " + testMap);
         Collections.sort(testMap, new ListMapComparator());
         System.out.println("After Sort: " + testMap);
    }
}
```

You will have some type safe warnings because I did not worry about these.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question but I had a requirement to sort a List of maps by its values' properties, this will work in your case too:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> sortedListOfMaps = someListOfMaps.sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> ((String) map.get("someKey")))).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        java.util.Collections.sort(data,
                new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "MM/dd/yyyy");

                    public int compare(final Map<String, String> map1,
                            final Map<String, String> map2) {
                        Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
                        try {
                            date1 = sdf.parse(map1.get("Date"));
                            date2 = sdf.parse(map2.get("Date"));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
                            return +1;
                        } else if (date1.compareTo(date2) == 0) {
                            return 0;
                        } else {
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit out of topic
this is a little util for watching sharedpreferences
based on upper answers
may be for someone this will be helpful

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void printAll() {
    Map<String, ?> prefAll = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getAll();
    if (prefAll == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<Map.Entry<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(prefAll.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, ?>>() {
        public int compare(final Map.Entry<String, ?> entry1, final Map.Entry<String, ?> entry2) {
            return entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey());
        }
    });
    Timber.i("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    Timber.i("Printing all sharedPreferences");
    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : list) {
        Timber.i("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    Timber.i("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve the same. One of the easiest ways to solve using Java 8 is given below :

As per your requirement, To sort in alphabetical order based on the map's key name

1st way :

```
list = list.stream()
           .sorted((a,b)-> (a.get("name")).compareTo(b.get("name")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or,

```
list = list.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(map->map.get("name")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2nd way :

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("name")));
```

3rd way :

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(map-> map.get("name")));
```