# Android: How to Order ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm saving details of product in a map and adding in  ArrayList< HashMap< String,String >> and setting in to a custom list adapter. I need to sort the values by price in it. How to achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try googling for map sorting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How sort an ArrayList of HashMaps holding several key-value pairs each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369573/how-sort-an-arraylist-of-hashmaps-holding-several-key-value-pairs-each)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pleas use the code below :

```
ArrayList< HashMap< String,String >> arrayList=populateArrayList();
    Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<HashMap< String,String >>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs,
                HashMap<String, String> rhs) {
            // Do your comparison logic here and retrn accordingly.
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

You can implement a `Comparator<Map<String, String>>` or `Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>`

[How sort an ArrayList of HashMaps holding several key-value pairs each?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369578/432903)
answers it well :

```
class MapComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>>{
    private final String key;

    public MapComparator(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int compare(Map<String, String> first,
                       Map<String, String> second){
        // TODO: Null checking, both for maps and values
        String firstValue = first.get(key);
        String secondValue = second.get(key);
        return firstValue.compareTo(secondValue);
    }
}

...
Collections.sort(arrayListHashMap, new MapComparator("value"));
```

Also look at [How to sort a Map on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/432903)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use this for your custom Sorting of objects in an Array List,

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getYOUROBJ1STR.compareTo(o2.getYOUROBJ2STR);
    }
}
```

Let me know  if you still face issues for sorting of Map

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using comparator and Collections class together if its a case of ArrayList

Check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/)

Thanks to Lars vogel

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this:-

[Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

[sorting a List of Map<String, String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155952/sorting-a-list-of-mapstring-string)

Hope it will helps you...